# admob campaign stuck on ready

Tags: admob

We recently started trying out Admob house campaigns and unfortunately found, that they are stuck on the "ready" state which is not really described what it is on their platform.

We tried to keep it simple with text campaigns running in banner components that we already use for other ads within our own app.

What we already checked is the setup of all the different accounts that one would need to achieve the same. [Link to account setup](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7591161#zippy=%2Cyour-account-status%2Cpayments%2Cpin-verification-status%2Cpolicy)

Went through it several times, still all is on ready state.

Comment: Other Stack Overflow users cannot see details within your admob account. You need to contact their support team, we cannot help you with this.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - seems to be a common issue though, just hoping for some clues from knowledgable users here. Support does not seem to do much and the community over there also not really helping, other than spamming everyone with the link above.